# Form helper select tag in a dependence object with elements from another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I´m newbie in Ruby on rails, and I´m trying to display a select with the ids from an object b) in an object a):

Object a) Function

Object b) Experience

function _form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :experience_id %><br />
<%= f.number_field :experience_id %>
```

I want to create a select which display the items in the table experience. I suppose it's a loop that loops through wich all elements of @ experience but not how. I have read about form helpers but I can not enlighten.

Thank so much

About Second Question

Thanks very much for your help. I tried like you proposed but the name of the select tag was not the correct name of the object and i don´t know how put it with that helper method. So i tried the same with another helper, select, and was success:

Option a)
select_tag :habilidad, options_for_select({"1" => 1, "2" => 2})

Resultant Source code:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="skill_habilidad">Habilidad</label><br />
    <select id="habilidad" NAME="habilidad"><option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option></select>
  </div>
```

Option b)
select(:skill, :habilidad, {"1" =>1, "2" => 2, "3" => 3, "4" => 4, "5" => 5})

Resultant source code:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="skill_habilidad">Habilidad</label><br />
    <select id="skill_habilidad" NAME="skill[habilidad]"><option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option></select> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `select_tag` with `options_for_select` like this:

```
<%= select_tag :skills, options_for_select((1..5).to_a.map { |val| [val,val] }) %>
```

You can replace `(1..5).to_a` for a variable.

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select

Answer (score 3):

You could use `f.collection_select` example:

```
<%= f.collection_select :experience_id, Experience.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true %>
```

Reference: [Rails Api Documentation :: Collection Select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `f.select`, example:

```
<%= f.label :experience_id %><br />
<%= f.select :experience_id, Experience.all.collect {|e| [ e.name, e.id ] }, { :include_blank => true } %>
```

As a example I used `e.name` to be the text on select option, you need to change to attribute that you want.

Reference:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

Answer (score 0):

this code its works for me

```
<%= f.select :id, Model.all.collect {|d| [ d.attributeN, d.attributeN ] }, {include_blank: 'None'}, class: 'form-control'%>
```